# Dynamically defining a method in BasicObject

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to dynamically define an instance method within `BasicObject`? If so, how?

```
class BasicObject
  def foo
    bar = "some_method_name"
    # I want to define a method `bar`
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:define_method` symbol as a parameter to the `send` method to create other methods for you,

```
Class BasicObject

  def foo
    input = "bar"

    BasicObject.send(:define_method, input) do
      puts "baz!"
    end
  end

end

b = BasicObject.new
b.foo
b.bar
# => "baz!"
```

Comment: Who upvoted this answer? Please do not randomly upvote answers.

Comment: Can you tell us if this answer was helpful?